# Convert time part of datetime2 to decimal/float

Tags: sql-server, function, datetime

I am looking for a way to built criteria to search all midday dates in datetime2 field (including those having NULL value). In other words, time part must be equal to 0.5 or NULL.
Here is what I tryied to find time number:

```
SELECT cast(GetDate() - DateDiff(day, 0, GetDate()) as decimal(4,4));
```

It gives me what I want, but when I pass it as criteria the following code fails with error

"Operand type clash: datetime2 is incompatible with int":

```
SELECT tbl_OrderDetailsSub.OrderDetailsSubID, ProcessedDate 
FROM tbl_OrderDetailsSub INNER JOIN tbl_OrderDetailsSubPl 
ON tbl_OrderDetailsSub.OrderDetailsSubID = tbl_OrderDetailsSubPl.OrderDetailsSubID 
INNER JOIN tbl_OrderDetails ON tbl_OrderDetailsSub.OrderDetailsID = tbl_OrderDetails.OrderDetailsID 
INNER JOIN tbl_Order ON tbl_OrderDetails.OrderID = tbl_Order.OrderID 
INNER JOIN tbl_Tooling ON tbl_OrderDetailsSubPl.TID = tbl_Tooling.TID LEFT OUTER JOIN tbl_ProdAct ON tbl_OrderDetailsSub.OrderDetailsSubID = tbl_ProdAct.ODSubID
WHERE (((tbl_Order.ProdTypeID)<>'S' Or (tbl_Order.ProdTypeID) Is Null) 
AND ((tbl_Order.CancelledDate) Is Null) 
AND ((tbl_Order.RefusingReason) Is Null)

AND (cast(isnull(ProcessedDate - DateDiff(day, 0, ProcessedDate),0.5) as decimal(4,4))=0.5)

AND ((tbl_Order.OrderType)<>'Pasiūlymas') 
AND ((tbl_Order.ShippedDate) Is Null));
```

I feel it is somehow related with **IsNull** function but cannot clarify it. I also tryied this line

```
AND (cast(ProcessedDate - DateDiff(day, 0, ProcessedDate) as decimal(4,4))=0.5 OR ProcessedDate is null)
```

... but got same error.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT tbl_OrderDetailsSub.OrderDetailsSubID,
       ProcessedDate
FROM   tbl_OrderDetailsSub
       INNER JOIN tbl_OrderDetailsSubPl
               ON tbl_OrderDetailsSub.OrderDetailsSubID = tbl_OrderDetailsSubPl.OrderDetailsSubID
       INNER JOIN tbl_OrderDetails
               ON tbl_OrderDetailsSub.OrderDetailsID = tbl_OrderDetails.OrderDetailsID
       INNER JOIN tbl_Order
               ON tbl_OrderDetails.OrderID = tbl_Order.OrderID
       INNER JOIN tbl_Tooling
               ON tbl_OrderDetailsSubPl.TID = tbl_Tooling.TID
       LEFT OUTER JOIN tbl_ProdAct
                    ON tbl_OrderDetailsSub.OrderDetailsSubID = tbl_ProdAct.ODSubID
WHERE  ( ( ( tbl_Order.ProdTypeID ) <> 'S'
            OR ( tbl_Order.ProdTypeID ) IS NULL )
         AND ( ( tbl_Order.CancelledDate ) IS NULL )
         AND ( ( tbl_Order.RefusingReason ) IS NULL )
         AND ( Cast(Isnull(Cast(ProcessedDate AS DATETIME) - Datediff(day, 0, Cast(ProcessedDate AS DATETIME)), 0.5) AS DECIMAL(4, 4)) = 0.5 )
         AND ( ( tbl_Order.OrderType ) <> 'Pasiūlymas' )
         AND ( ( tbl_Order.ShippedDate ) IS NULL ) );
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is because you are trying to subTract an `INT` from a `DATETIME2`, and `INT` cannot be [implicitly converted](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191530.aspx) to a `DATETIME2`. This part works:

```
SELECT cast(GetDate() - DateDiff(day, 0, GetDate()) as decimal(4,4));
```

Because `GETDATE()` is a `DATETIME`, not `DATETIME2`, and `INT` can be implicitly converted to a `DATETIME`. If you check the execution plan XML you will see

> CONVERT(decimal(4,4),getdate()-CONVERT_IMPLICIT(datetime,datediff(day,'1900-01-01 00:00:00.000',getdate()),0),0)

Where you can see that the `INT` result of `datediff(day,'1900-01-01 00:00:00.000',getdate())` is being implicitly converted to a datetime.

You can replicate your same error using:

```
DECLARE @D DATETIME2 = GETDATE();
SELECT cast(@D - DateDiff(day, 0, @D) as decimal(4,4));
```

I am not 100% sure why the implicit conversion was removed for the new types of `DATE` and `DATETIME2` in SQL Server 2008, but it was, so we have to deal with it.

One way around this would be to just convert your `DATETIME2` to a `DATETIME`:

```
DECLARE @D DATETIME2 = GETDATE();
SELECT cast(CAST(@D AS DATETIME) - DateDiff(day, 0, @D) as decimal(4,4));
```

However, i would be inclined to avoid implicit conversions completely and use:

```
DECLARE @D DATETIME2 = GETDATE();
SELECT  CAST(DATEDIFF(SECOND, '00:00', CAST(@D AS TIME)) / 86400.0 AS DECIMAL(10, 4));
```

The premise being converting your date to a time, then finding out the number of seconds past the start of the day it is, then dividing this by the total seconds in the day will give your decimal time.